# Is the total count of my impressions on admob include both the banner and interstitial ads count?

Tags: admob, banner, interstitial

I have an app that uses both banner and Interstitials .
I use Admob. Does the count of impressions which is seen on the admob dashboard include both banner and interstitials together or only interstitials?

Answer (score 0):

It includes both.

You can filter by ad unit on the `Monetize` tab:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Can you answer another question....? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38186541/is-it-allowed-to-incentivize-users-for-watching-the-admob-ads-and-not-clicking-o?noredirect=1#comment63798716_38186541